# Prove that Markov's inequality is not tight

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For any fixed random variable $X\geq0$ with $EX\leq\infty$, $$\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\lambda\mathbb{P}(X\geq\lambda)}{EX}=0$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've attempted doing a proof by contradiction, assuming that the equality is not satisfied, but I am unsure as to how I proceed from there.

Comment: Are you sure this is the statement you want to prove ? This is not usually what is meant by "Markov is not tight"... and your statement is obvious.

Comment: Usually, 'Markov is not tight' refers to the fact that the function $\lambda \geq 0 \mapsto \lambda P(X\ge \lambda)$, bounded from above by $E[X]$ by Markov, has a null limit as $\lambda$ goes to $\infty$ ...

Comment: Ok, this is much better now :-)

Comment: @Olivier My bad I had made a typo when writing the question

Comment: The division remains unnecessary, no ?

Comment: This is the way the statement has been written in my source. I have tried to show that the contradictory case implies that the expectation is infinite but I am struggling.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Sorry the question was not written correctly, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_n$ be any sequence diverging to $\infty$. Check the two assumptions of the Dominated Convergence Theorem :

- $\lambda_n 1_{X \geq \lambda_n} \le X$, and this r.v. is integrable (independent of \lambda) given your assumption.
- $\lambda_n 1_{X \geq \lambda_n}\to 0$ a.s. since $P(X<\infty)=1$.

to conclude that

$$\lambda_n P(X \geq \lambda_n)\to 0$$ (while being bounded by $E[X]$, which you already knew)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks!